# SWRevealViewController not able to call from the appdelegate.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I am calling SWRevealViewController in Appdelegate.m

```
SWRevealViewController *svc = self.revealViewController;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    FrontVC *homeVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FrontVC"];
    [svc setFrontViewController:homeVC animated:NO];
    [svc revealToggleAnimated:YES];
```

But i am not able to load FrontVC controlller .
what is right way to call

Comment: Isnt it easier to follow the detailed tutorial in [Appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)? U can implements it in storyboard, just put the start pointer to the SWRevealViewController then u done

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 2.2

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController

self.window?.rootViewController = sw

let cv = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IDOFCONTROLLER") as! NAMEOFCONTROLLER

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cv)

sw.pushFrontViewController(navigationController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this one helps.

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        // this any item in list you want navigate to
        yourHomeViewController *home = (yourHomeViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leid"];

        yourSideMenuViewController *slidemenu = (yourSideMenuViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuView"];

        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:home];

        UINavigationController *smVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:slidemenu];

        // define rear and frontviewcontroller
        SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:smVC frontViewController:nav];

        // make it as root
        self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```

Comment: This works perfect for me, the only problem is that - It hides a back button for me as Im navigating to a child view controller.

Comment: yes I managed to make it work for me. But you need to have a start indicator in the SWRevealViewController in your storyboard, then put the above code on app delegate

Answer (score 0):

We can't call RevealViewController in App Delegate.
You can directly add this in Your ViewController for Front & rear.

Comment: there i have added .all is working after loged in user .i want avoid the user to go login screen so from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method i want to call SWRevealViewController . to go home screen.

Comment: Give the user a BOOL value in NSUserDefault that indicator if the user have not logged out yet, put it in Appdelegate then check when app start and go straight to your needed ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared and initialized revealViewController anything like this?

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
    @property (strong, nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *revealViewController;
@end
```

/* ... */

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.revealViewController = /* ... init ... */;
    /* ... your code here ... */
}
```

Comment: using property my error is gone but my FrontVC not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use a storyboard but did it like this:

```
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController    alloc] initWithRearViewController:menuViewController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

SWRevealViewController *viewController = revealController;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can put the start indicator in the SWRevealViewController in ur storyboard, give the login VC a name

```
//if user is logged in - In login VC 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:1 forKey:isLogged];

//In Appdelegate
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:isLogged] == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"have data");
//Start straight into normal SWRevealVC
        self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController]; 
    }
    else
    {

//If not, make your root VC the login viewcontroller
        UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

        self.window.rootViewController = rootController;
    }
```